# Canvas Animate Clipping Mask Path

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, image-clipping

I want to (I have accomplished 1-3):

1. grab an image from the page
2. add it to a canvas element
3. clip the image to a mask
4. move (animate) the mask around the image

I have accomplished the first 3, but cannot figure out how to move the mask.. Please help!

```
// get the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');  

// get a div from the page
var stuff = document.getElementsByName('testElem')[0];

// add a class to the div
stuff.setAttribute('class', 'pleaseWork');
var newImage = new Image();

// get the background image of the div
var bgClass = document.getElementsByClassName('pleaseWork')[0].style.backgroundImage;

  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 75;
  var offset = 50;  

  // clip the context to create a circular clipping mask
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.clip();

// on load put the image into the clipping mask
newImage.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(newImage,0,0);
}

// put the background image from the div into the canvas (without the url())
newImage.src = bgClass.replace(/^url|[\(\)]/g, '');
```

How can I move (animate) the clipping mask from the canvas to show different parts of the clipped image?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your clip+drawing code in a function and call that function inside an animation loop:

Example code and a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/07mzbat9/

Drawing Function:

```
function draw(){

    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

    // save the unclipped context
    ctx.save();

    // draw a circular path
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,PI2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();

    // create a clipping path from the circular path
    // use the clipping path to restrict drawing 
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

    // restore the unclipped context (to remove clip)
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Animation loop:

```
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var cx=50;
var cy=50;
var radius=35;
var PI2=Math.PI*2;

// animate the mask across the canvas
function animate(time){
    if(cx-radius>cw || cy-radius>ch){return;}
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    cx+=0.2;
    cy+=0.2;
    draw();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @markE that is awesome! However, I am facing a problem based on needing to grab an image from a background of a div (have to do this b/c the markup structure) and placing it inside the canvas to move the mask. I updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/07mzbat9/2/. If you have any ideas I would appreciate it, as this has stumped me for a few days. Thanks!!

Comment: Here's my fiddle modified to grab the background image of a div element: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/56wqqmqe/ Good luck with your project!